# Extract value with applied condition in jmeter using regular expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract every text message where nickname is Mack Dack. how can i do that using regularExpression extractor

```
{"messages":[{"from":{"nickname":"Mack Dack","participantId":2,"type":"Agent"},"index":2,"type":"ParticipantJoined","utcTime":1600262148000},{"from":{"nickname":"Mack Dack","participantId":2,"type":"Agent"},"index":4,"text":"Starting the bot: ToBi","type":"Message","utcTime":1600262151000},{"from":{"nickname":"Sonaltest Garg","participantId":1,"type":"Client"},"index":5,"text":"Starting the bot: ToBi","type":"Message","utcTime":1600262161000},{"from":{"nickname":"Mack Dack","participantId":2,"type":"Agent"},"index":7,"text":"Welcome! I am Watson. How can I help?","type":"Message","utcTime":1600262163000},{"from":{"nickname":"Sonaltest Garg","participantId":1,"type":"Client"},"index":8,"text":"Welcome! I am Watson. How can I help?","type":"Message","utcTime":1600262174000}],"chatEnded":false,"statusCode":0,"alias":"118","secureKey":"a20dfd835cd8d2199017","userId":"00765F620FFE00A2","chatId":"000BEaFP3FBS003W","nextPosition":9}
```

my purpose is to select only those text message which are coming from mack dack and compare them with my local json file if both message are same then send message which is same  by Sonaltest Garg

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions for parsing [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is not the best idea, normally you should rather be using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) but in particular your case you won't be able to get benefits of [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) as when it comes to JSON Arrays querying parent attributes using children as filter is not possible.

So I would rather recommend using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
def messages = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..[?(@.type == "Message")]')
messages.findAll { message ->
    message.from.nickname == 'Mack Dack'
}.eachWithIndex { message, index ->
    vars.put('message_' + (index + 1), message.text)
}
```

As the result you will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

- `message_1=Starting the bot: ToBi`
- `message_2=Welcome! I am Watson. How can I help?`

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article to learn what these `prev` and `vars` shorthands mean

Comment: how can i store this result in array so i can pass the message  with http  request sampler